# Personal Views for SharePoint List

Tags: sharepoint-online

I have created a SharePoint classic experience list. I need to create two different views. The first, shows all items but is only viewable to me. Would this be a private view? Second, how can I create another view for users to only view list items that they created? I have tried searching the web for an example and have not had any luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. To show the view to all users, we have to select the option "Create as Public View" on the View creation page.

To create a view, Navigate to the List Settings Page and then scroll to the bottom of the page to view all views available for List.[image]

2. **Show items created by the users**

- Navigate to List Settings Page
- Scroll to the bottom of the page
- Click Create View
- Choose Standard View
- In the View creation page, add the view name
- Then select "Create a Public View" in the Audience section
- Then scroll down to the Filter section.
- Add the configuration as **Created By is equal to [Me]**
  [image]
- Then save the view.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Thank you! This helps, but for the first one I should have been more specific in asking my question. The view that will show all items created by everyone, and I only want one person to have access to that view. How do I go about that?

Comment: Create a view as Personal View without applying the filter.

Comment: The personal view would be for someone else though, not me. So how can I apply that personal view to allow them to see it, not me? Or would that person have to create their own peronal view.

Comment: That person has to create the view on their own.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the solution that @Shantha provided, i would like to point out that there is another way of achieving the same result.

The screenshots below are taken from my Dev O365 Tenant.

1. First you can create a list and cut the inheritance.
2. Provide access rights(Contribute Access Level, not Edit) to the groups of people that are required to view and edit only their own entries.
3. Provide access rights(Edit or Full Control Access Level), to your own account or to a Group of people that would have to view and edit all of the entries that might reside within the SharePoint List in question.

[image]

4. Navigate into Advanced Settings, from the List Settings screen and check the two below options.

[image]

Now if you insert an entry to the List the group, declared as members in my case, will only view and edit items, they created.Screenshot from an Member's account:

[image]

Also, the other group, declared as owners, will be able to view and edit all of the List Items since the have Edit or above rights. Screenshot from an Owner's account:

[image]

The goal you might achieve with the above way, is that each user in the member's group will always have access to list items that he created and none else.
In addition, the supervising group will have access to check all of the List item, in case of validation of information entered.

Another reason i prefer the above approach, is that a user will not be able to simply navigate to the view and switch views and have access to something that he shouldn't.

Just a heads up, in order for this solution to work, you will have to ensure a user cannot change the List's Settings, which means adjusting permission levels on the Site Collection Level. On the List Level you already have them configured from step 2, since you declared only contribute access level for the member's group.

[EDIT]: This way you will not have to create multiple views on the list.